# For Angular2 Router3, why isn't my Parent Route's Guard called every time I switch between its child routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I have a Guard for my parent route that isn't always called when viewing the child routes. It is called when the first child is loaded, but if I switch to another child within the same parent, the parent's Guard isn't referenced again. Here's what I have:

```
export const AppRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: 'app',
        component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        children: [
            {path: 'child1', component: Child1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
            {path: 'child2', component: Child2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
            {path: 'error/:status', component: ErrorComponent}
        ]
    }
];
```

Is there a way to make sure LoggedInGuard is called every time I switch between child1 and child2?

Comment: There is a new guard `canActivateChild` on it's way. It should be included with the next update. I guess this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That sounds perfect, thanks! Do you know roughly when that update is scheduled for?

Comment: I'm expecting it every day (since about 10 days ;-) )

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hahahaha ! :)

Comment: canActivateChild arrived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
canActivateChild: [LoggedInGuard]
```

Is arrived , so you can achieve this by canActivateChild of router.